# C++ Operator overloading: error pointer being freed was not allocated

Tags: c++, macos, malloc, free, destructor

I made a `Matrix4` class and i get a weird error when the operation is finished. 
The error only occurs in OSX (Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40)) and not in
MinGW with gcc 4.8.2. I use `-framework openGL -framework Cocoa`.

---

Error: **malloc:**  error for object 0x7fff53d20760: pointer being freed was not allocated
 **set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug**

```
Matrix4 a;
Matrix4 b;
Matrix4 c=a*b;
```

This is the class:

```
class Matrix4 :public Uniform{
    ...
};
```

---

**Solution:**

the destructor of the class `Uniform` was wrong:

```
struct Uniform{
    int uID=0;
public:
    virtual void* getData()=0;
    virtual void uploadUniform()=0;
    virtual ~Uniform(){
        free(&uID);
    }
};
```

Comment: You're leaking memory. Every `new` needs a corresponding `delete`. Same goes for `new[]` / `delete[]`. Not to mention the other undefined behavior

Comment: `operator *` returns a dangling reference to a temporary that then gets destroyed, for a start. And you have lots of memory leaks (you allocate memory but never free any).

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Thanks, I just fixed that, but I dont think that this is the problem, because it works fine in gcc.

Comment: @AlanStokes how should i implement the operator to avoid that?

Comment: `operator*` should return by value not by reference.

Comment: i found my error, there really was a pointer being freed, that wasnt allocated. The class Uniform freed an int...